# is it possible to find the shortest path between an origin node and multiple destination nodes? Using Networkx or OSMnx

Tags: python, networkx, openstreetmap, shortest-path, osmnx

```
orig_node = ox.nearest_nodes(G, orig_x, orig_y)

dest_nodes = ox.nearest_nodes(G, dest_x, dest_y)


route = ox.distance.shortest_path(G, orig_node, dest_nodes, weight='length')

ValueError: orig and dest must either both be iterable or neither must be iterable
```

orig_node is a singular osm node id -> 1969350363

dest_nodes is a list of osm node ids -> [2345488820, 2345484728, 3173262522, 1837961033]

I want to find the shortest route between the orig_node and all of the dest_nodes

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Just make your orig_node variable a list with length equal to that of dest_nodes.

Comment: Like this? 

orig_node = [1969350363, 1969350363,1969350363,1969350363]
dest_nodes = [2345488820, 2345484728, 3173262522, 1837961033]

The result produces a nested list with 4 routes from the orig_node to each of the respective dest_nodes. However I would like the shortest route between all the nodes following any route

Answer (score 0):

To find the shortest weighted path between pairs of origin and destination nodes, you just need to find the `min`, using the path length as the `key`. Here's a minimal reproducible example:

```py
import osmnx as ox
G = ox.graph_from_place("Piedmont, CA, USA", network_type="drive")

# return shortest weighted path between sets of origins and destinations
def find_shortest(G, orig, dest, weight):
    results = []
    for o, d in zip(orig, dest):
        path = ox.shortest_path(G, o, d, weight)
        dist = sum(ox.utils_graph.get_route_edge_attributes(G, path, "length"))
        results.append((o, d, path, dist))
    return min(results, key=lambda x: x[3])

# pick some random origins and destinations
n = list(G.nodes)
dest = [n[20], n[30], n[40], n[50]]
orig = [n[0]] * len(dest)

# get the origin, destination, path, and distance of the shortest route
o, d, path, dist = find_shortest(G, orig, dest, "length")
```

Comment: Apologies for my ignorance, but I think you have miss understood. I would like to find the shortest path that stops at every destination node. 

I require the shortest route the goes through the origin node and all of the destination nodes. The destination nodes can be visited in any order within the route.

Many thanks :)